# How to compare Auth::check() to based on where clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to set a condition where I need to check the current user if she/he is the approver of the Document. If the user is the approver **accept** and **reject** button will show to the view.

Controller:

```
public function documentsSentForApproval()
{

    $pendingDocumentLists = DB::table('approve_document')->select('documents.title', 'documents.content',
        'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'approve_document.dateReceived', 'documents.id')
    ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approve_document.document_id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
    ->join('approves', 'approves.id', '=', 'approve_document.approve_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approves.approver_id')
    ->where('approver_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->orWhere('requestedBy', '=', Auth::id())
    ->get();

    return view ('document.pending')
    ->with('pendingDocumentLists', $pendingDocumentLists);
}
```

As you can see here in the `where` clause the `approver_id` is the one who gonna approve the document. I just having a little problem where the `requestedBy` column is the one who create the document for approvals.

Logic:

I need to check if the current user `!= approver_id`. If not **accept** and **reject** will not shown to the view.

View:

```
<table class = "table">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Approver</th>
            <th>Date Sent</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($pendingDocumentLists as $list)
            <tr class = "info">

                <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ strip_tags(substr($list->content, 0, 50)) }} {{ strlen($list->content) > 50 ? "..." : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ date('M, j, Y', strtotime($list->dateReceived)) }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href = ""><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-open"> Read</button></a>
                    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</button>
                    @if (Auth::check() == )<!--I'm stuck here-->
                        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Approve</button>
                        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"> Reject</button>
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

User Interface:

[image]

**Update**

I added `$data['permission'] = ['approver_id'];` as @Mayank said and this is what I do in my view.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($pendingDocumentLists as $list)
        <tr class = "info">

                <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ strip_tags(substr($list->content, 0, 50)) }} {{ strlen($list->content) > 50 ? "..." : '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ date('M, j, Y', strtotime($list->dateReceived)) }}</td>
                <td>
            @if ($permission != Auth::id())
                <a href = ""><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-open"> Read</button></a>
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> Delete</button>
            @else
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Approve</button>
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"> Reject</button>
            @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: You can't use $list->approve_id == Auth::id() ?

Comment: Try add it to select statement

Comment: It's already working. I just added `approves.approves_id` in my select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller in documentsSentForApproval function add `approver_id` to our select

```
public function documentsSentForApproval()
{

    $pendingDocumentLists = DB::table('approve_document')->select('documents.title', 'documents.content',
        'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'approve_document.dateReceived', 'documents.id', 'approves.approver_id')
    ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approve_document.document_id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
    ->join('approves', 'approves.id', '=', 'approve_document.approve_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approves.approver_id')
    ->where('approver_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->orWhere('requestedBy', '=', Auth::id())
    ->get();

    return view ('document.pending')
    ->with('pendingDocumentLists', $pendingDocumentLists);
}
```

Then in your view file you can do this:

```
@if (Auth::id() == $list->approver_id)
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Approve</button>
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"> Reject</button>
@endif
```

Comment: Hey what a nice solution didn't notice this will work. Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check it on your view than pass this value from your controller to your view in an array like:

```
$data['permission'] = 10;
```

On your view:

```
if($permission != Auth::id())
{
    // show option or what ever you want
}
else
{
    // dont show option or what ever you want
}
```

Comment: Why should I put the $data as 10?

Comment: just for example bro :)

Comment: I'm little bit confuse of what should be the value of my `$data` :p

Comment: Can I passed the value as `approver_id`?

Comment: Yes, the data return by your query is like:
$data['id'] = something, $data['permission'] = $arr['approver_id'];
Now use this permission as described above

Comment: I tried your solution but it says `Undefined variable: permission` in my view.

Comment: Have you pass this $data variable from your controller to your view ?

Comment: I tried it by this. `$data['permission'] = ['approver_id'];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121036/discussion-between-mayank-pandey-and-francisunoxx).